# Quote box coloring, should it stand out more?

Tags: feature-request, design

When I'm reading a post with quoted material, the quote doesn't seem to stand out to me, maybe it's something about it being yellow, but I cannot see it.

Quoth the raven

> Nevermore

The blue here on meta stands out, but on Chem.SE it's a pale yellow which doesn't seem to stand out to me.

[image: pale yellow]

I'm not recommending making it permanganate purple, but if others also have a problem seeing the quote box in Chem.se, perhaps we could darken it or change the color altogether.

**Important Edit**: The coloring actually appears darker on my laptop and it does stand out a bit. Since it appears to vary from computer to computer, my question still stands.

Thoughts?

Comment: I personally find it rather nice this way as I really like how unobtrusive it is. On all my computers I can see it also quite well. What would your suggestion be for a colour?

Comment: No particular suggestion for a color. I wish a screenshot would show the problem I'm having (it doesn't, because it's in full color on my other computer.) The text box appears completely white to me except for a light yellow stripe down the side.

Comment: I agree that it can be difficult to see and personally wouldn't mind having it be a tiny bit darker. However, I suspect that the visibility probably varies from one individual to another so we'll probably need more input.

Comment: @MelanieShebel Are the colours of your system correctly calibrated? Unfortunately, most factory settings of current displays are too blue (i.e. the colour temperature is too high). Since you describe the blockquote on meta, which is merely rgb(239,240,241), with “the blue here on meta stands out”, your settings could be too blue, too.

Comment: I'd say this is potentially a question as part of a bigger discussion. Looking through meta its been a while since the site was designed, and, looking at some of the newer SE sites, I think it could look ... better, for want of a better word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote box here on Chemistry seems to be exactly the same as the quote box over at German and Travel. Thus, I suspect very strongly, that it is the same quote-box networt wide — minus a few ‘lucky’ sites (TeX.SX for example) that got a site design before the quote box appearance was frozen.

Personally, I have no problem seeing the yellow quote box on the main site — but I do wonder why the quote box is blue on meta for you. To me, it is grey.

Comment: Blue grey. :P I must just be one of the lucky few that just can't see the box here. No biggie. :)